# Why don't some JS Files show in Sources tab of Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, developer-tools

I can't open certain js files in the Chrome Developer Tools Sources tab for debugging.
I can see the file contents fine in the Network Response.
I looked at the Headers and there doesn't seem to be anything specific to the files which are not viewable?
For example in the following Screenshot there is no option to "Open in Sources Panel"

No Option to Open in Sources Panel

[image: 1]

This doesn't seem specific to Chrome as I see similar behavior in the Firefox Debugger with these exact same files.

Any ideas why certain files can't be viewed in the Sources Tab and hence can't be debugged?

I observe this in Chrome Version 110.0.5481.178
I expect to see the option to open the .js file in the Sources Panel.
For example:

First Option in Menu to Open in Sources Panel

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed what appears to be a new problem when attempting to debug JSP output containing Javascript. The JSP returns html/javascript that can be viewed in the Elements tab but the Source tab displays no content for the response. The Network > Response tab likewise shows no content. This is a new issue for me and it appears across browsers (Chrome Version 111.0.5563.147 (Official Build) (64-bit), FF, Edge). I'm not using source maps and have this disabled in the browser.